# How to identify this design feature I don't know the term for

Tags: text, style-identification

I'm often searching for already created works/templates etc, to get some idea of how things are done. The thing is, I have an idea of something and I don't even know what it is called, and as a result I don't know what to look for in order to get an idea of ways it can be done. I'll try to describe it as I can:

For example you have a site or pre-print document with a beautiful design, but in some part of it you may want to add some description or explanation of something or anything else, for about 5-10 sentences. It's like a big notice, but not a notice.

I can't google it, I simply don't know what to google for. I want to see how people create this kind of expression of notice (a big notice), the same way people create ribbons for example.

Picture as requested(paint, lol!):

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pull+quote+design&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLr6vxw4zLAhXKshQKHRGMDzMQ_AUIBygB&biw=1504&bih=844) the kind of thing you're talking about maybe?

Comment: Not really. I added a picture to make it more understandable

Comment: Using you image explain what you want in just a few sentences. I'll edit your question then so you can get some better answers.

Comment: be my guest :) I would very appreciate it

Comment: Hmmm. Are you referring to the white part of your image? Where it would be left blank and you could add text later?

Comment: Yes! The design of white part... of course it's always the different design

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Pull Quote?

Page 2: http://journalism.uoregon.edu/~sasbury/whatsitcalled.pdf

> Pull quotes, decks, subheads and captions all fall under the broad
>   category of **points of entry** —call-out text that invites the reader
>   into the story

Or, (from wikipedia)

> a key phrase, quotation, or excerpt that has been pulled from an
>   article and used as a graphic element, serving to entice readers into
>   the article or to highlight a key topic. It is typically placed in a
>   larger or distinctive typeface and on the same page.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the information in the link  to the actual answer so that the information is self-contained. This is "standard" practice on stackexchange, since links can die.